# Spectral signatures difference between a raw image and an atmospherically corrected image

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, digital-image-processing, land-cover, atmospheric-correction

I did atmospheric correction of Landsat 5 image by Quick atmospheric correction method(QUAC), now I want to compare atmospheric corrected spectral signatures from ENVI QUAC with the input spectral
signatures of a Raw image. What differences are there, and why these differences occur?
[image]

***Spectral signatures of a Raw image (Landcover features)***

[image]

***Spectral signatures of an Atmospherically corrected image***

Comment: @Aaron sir kindly view this question now.

Comment: Then, ehy did you want to do atmospheric correction?